# Need help making string input return a histogram that counts frequency of letter pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, histogram, frequency

I need to write a function(s) that takes strings as inputs and outputs a histogram of the frequency of letter pairs, in descending order.

I've managed to write a function that returns single char count, but I can't figure out how to do pairs.

Here's what I have thus far:

```
var string = "etc";
var histogram = {};

for (var i = 0, len = string.length; i < len; i++) {
    var char = string[i];
    if ((string[i] !== " ") && (string[i] !== " ")) {
        histogram[char] = (histogram[char] || 0) + 1;
    }
};

console.log(histogram);
```

The function works, and I was able to get it to leave all empty spaces out of the histogram. I'm stuck as to where to go from here, though. How to get it to evaluate pairs, and how to leave out any single char (those not followed by another char)... Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand `(string[i] !== " ") && (string[i] !== " ")` Why do you check `string[i]` twice?

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing something with `string[i]+string[i+1]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make use of `string[i+1]` to get the next letter in the pair.

And to avoid accessing outside the array when you use `string[i+1]`, the limit of the loop should be `string.length-1`.

```js
var string = "this is a good thing";
var histogram = {};

for (var i = 0, len = string.length - 1; i < len; i++) {
  if ((string[i] !== " ") && (string[i + 1] !== " ")) {
    let pair = string.substr(i, 2);
    histogram[pair] = (histogram[pair] || 0) + 1;
  }
};

console.log(histogram);
```

Comment: Good catch on the redundancy - I meant to check for " " once but accidentally left the && in as I was trying out different conditions. I'm new to JS, but I'm reading through your solution to understand it and it makes total sense. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, breaking the problem down into tiny pieces:

```js
const inPairs = (xs) => 
  [...xs].reduce((a, x, i) => i == 0 ? a : [...a, xs[i - 1] + x], [])

const pairFreq = str => str         //   "this is a good thing"
  .split (/\s+/)                    //=> ["this","is","a","good","thing"]
  .filter (s => s.length > 1)       //=> ["this","is","good","thing"]
  .flatMap (inPairs)                //=> ["th","hi","is","is","go","oo","od","th","hi","in","ng"]
  .reduce ( (a, s) => ({...a, [s]: (a[s] || 0) + 1}), {})
                                    //=> {"th":2,"hi":2,"is":2,"go":1,"oo":1,"od":1,"in":1,"ng":1}

console .log (
  pairFreq('this is a good thing')
)
```

Obviously you could inline `inPairs` if you chose.  I like this style of transformation, simply stringing together steps that move me toward my end goal.

Comment: Well I have to go look up some string functions... thank you for sharing here.

Comment: @TCooper: note that the only String function here is `split`.  The others, `filter`, 'flatMap`. and `reduce`, work on arrays.  Of course our helper function and our main function are both string functions too.

Comment: Awesome alternative. I definitely learned a lot from this one. Thanks!

Comment: @ScottSauyet Oh.. DUH. Because split could somehow output one string XD. You even have in the comments... either way, still have to look up flatmap's uses, and think more about using reduce effectively too. Here's your +1 I forgot yesterday. Mainly just trying to say I appreciate the approach here. Very readable, avoids looping. How I'd like to write my own code. I would've done the same as Barmar.

Comment: @TCooper: A good friend has made it one of his life's goals to never code another `for`-loop.